# STRLEN Error - String Type

Tags: c

I am not sure why this is not working out. I have attached my code and error. The line to focus on is `if (strlen (String() >= MAX_STR_LEN-1))`

I am trying to use the built in function `strlen` to compare `String`, which is a temporary value that holds the current characters that my input file has. I would like to compare the size of `String` to my variable `MAX_STR_LEN` which is just an integer of the value 256. Please let me know if I can provide any more information.

```
 void ReadData(FILE *InputFile, DArray *DynamicArrayPtr)
  {
   Data TempData;             /* temp variable to hold data   */
   int lcv = 1;               /* loop control variable        */
   int strLen;                /* The actual input string length */
   char String[MAX_STR_LEN];          /* temp variable to hold string */

   while (EOF != fscanf(InputFile, "%s", String))
     {
      /* Insert code here to make sure the input data is not too long*/
    if (strlen (String() >= MAX_STR_LEN-1)) {
    }
    else {
        printf("Error, input string too long \n");
    }
      TempData.Num = lcv++;
      strcpy(TempData.String, String);
      PushToDArray(DynamicArrayPtr, &TempData);
     } /* while() */
  } /* ReadData() */
```

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5aEM.png)

Comment: Comparing strings with `strlen` is a very bad idea. How should that work anyway?

Comment: `String` is not a function. Why are you calling it? Get rid of the parentheses and the unused variable. The error message is quite clear.

Comment: And Yoda-conditions not using you should.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `strlen (String() >= MAX_STR_LEN-1))` - what on Earth does this mean?

Comment: Note that if the string is too long, then the `fscanf` will crash your program before you even get to the `if` statement.

Comment: I think I made it clear that I just want to compare a single word "e.g dog" to my variable MAX_STR_LEN and see if it is greater or less than. At such print a statement. This word is in an input file and I hope to fix this issue and create a new test file with many words and one word that is over 256 bytes long to see if it all works. Hope that clears  in up guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error occurred due to this 
    if (strlen (String() >= MAX_STR_LEN-1)) {
        }
remove the () after String. String is not function. 
strlen return the length of String. The following will work fine.

```
if(strlen(String) >= MAX_STR_LEN-1){
}
```

Comment: Thank you @yabets, that solved the error but the result when testing is not correct. Now any input even just the word dog is being said to be longer than 256 bytes.  http://imgur.com/a/zSYnM

Comment: if(strlen(String) >= MAX_STR_LEN-1){
    }
is using >=, therefore the String needs to be greater than MAX_STR_LEN-1. For small words you need <= sign instead of >=

Comment: Srry for that silly question. I had thought I was in my else statement. That is now working thank you!